# Infinite recursion in jQuery plugin subfunction

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, infinite-loop

I wrote the following jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.imageSlide = function(options){
      $(this).imageSlide.nextSlide();
      console.log("imageslide");
    };

    $.fn.imageSlide.nextSlide = function(){
      console.log("nextslide");
      $this = $(this);
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**Some background:**

I want an image slider plugin, to crossfade backgrounds (for performance reasons I cannot use the [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) plugin). I want to expose several functions to the user: the imageSlide plugin "constructor" and several other functions, e.g. `imageSlide.nextSlide` and `imageSlide.previousSlide`, to enable the user to perform these actions from outside the plugin.

The `imageSlide` function needs to call the `imageSlide.nextSlide function`, to slide in (or fade in) the first image.

**Problem:**

It seems that the line `$this = $(this);` triggers an infinite recursion of the `imageSlide.nextSlide` function.

- Why is this happening?
- It seems that `$.fn.imageSlide.nextSlide = function(){};` is not the right way to expose another function in a jQuery plugin. How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is causing the error, but there is no need to put all your static methods in the jQuery prototype.

Try exposing the plugin using something like:

```
(function($) {

// The constructor of your plugin:
var imageSlide = function(elems, options) {
    this.elems = elems; // the targets from the jQuery selector
    this.options = options;
};

// the public inherited methods:
imageSlide.prototype = {
    nextSlide: function() {
        console.log('nextSlide called');
    }
};

// extending the jQuery prototype and returning only one instance:
$.fn.imageSlide = function(options) {
    return new imageSlide(this, options);
};

})(jQuery);
```

Now you can call the plugin and it's methods like this:

```
var myGallery = $('#gallery').imageSlide();
myGallery.nextSlide();
```

Comment: Does this return a jQuery object? I want to call the subfunctions directly on the jQuery object, like this: `$('#gallery').imageSlide.nextSlide()`; this way I only pollute one "namespace" (imageSlide) for my plugin, but I don't need to keep track of the image sliders I have created.

Comment: Yes, you can chain them like that using `$('#gallery').imageSlide().nextSlide();` but that will create a new instance.